# Run a Ruby file within a Vagrant provisioning Bash script

Tags: ruby, bash, vagrant

I have a Vagrant provisioning Bash file that contains this command:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://bakeware.herokuapp.com/bake/install)"
```

For some reason it doesn't work. It appears to according to the output:

```
==> nerves: => bake version 0.2.4 installed to ~/.bake/bin
==> nerves: Be sure to add ~/.bake/bin to your path
```

But the `~/.bake` directory hasn't been created. It doesn't work either if I `wget` the install file and run `ruby install` within the Vagrant provision script.

It works fine if I `vagrant ssh` in and run the commands. How would I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vagrant is provisioning using a privileged user, `root`, if you'd like a line to run as the default user, `vagrant`, then you'd have to run the provision script with `privileged: false`

like so

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo $(whoami)", privileged: false
```